# NGINX redirects to http

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am a newbie to NGINX and have been trying to get this problem sorted out.

Here is the NGINX configuration that works pretty well for most of the part, however when a request is placed without the trailing slash at the end, it redirects to http://$host instead of https://$host. It was forwarding with the port earlier, but I turned off port_in_redirect, which disabled showing up the port number in the browser.

Somehow https://domain.com/xyz/abc still gets redirected to http://domain.com/xyz/abc/

My guess is try_files is somehow not retaining the domain name

I am sure there is something wrong in the configuration, but I have no deep insights on whats causing it

Any inputs is highly appreciate

```
    server {
    listen  8080;
    server_name _;

    location /xyz/abc {
            alias /var/www/html/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /xyz/abc/index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/xyz/foo/(.*) {
            return 301 https://$host/xyz/abc/foo/$1;
    }
```

Below is the curl output

```
curl -I https://domain.com/xyz/abc
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.3
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2016 08:18:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: http://domain.com/xyz/abc/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Your server listens to port `8080`, but your curl goes to default port (which is 443 for https), so you have to show that part of config too

Comment: Nginx is installed in server A and server B on port 8080, which is load balanced to a domain name. I do not have a mention to port 443 other than the explicit redirects during /xyz/foo/.I am doing https://$host for nginx to preserve the request line in the browser

Comment: Hi do you have a answer for this.